# Copy a line containing a string to another file in shell script

Tags: string, file, shell, copy

I am new to shell scripting and I am trying to figure out the following.

How to search a file for a line containing a particular string and copy that line to a new file if the line is present?

Comment: `grep "string-regex" in_file >>out_file`. Change `grep` to `fgrep` if you do not care about regular expressions. Add `--` before `"string...` if `string` starts with a dash `-`. Change `>>` to `>` to overwrite, instead of append to, `out_file`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
grep "string" file >copyFile
```

This would create a new file or empty an existing file.

```
grep "string" file >>copyFile
```

This would create a new file or append found string to an existing file.

Nota: `"string"` is a *regex*. Take a look at `man grep` for syntax.